# Issue with Bootstrap 3 media mobile display of navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, responsive-design, padding, fluid-layout

I'm trying to figure out why my changes to the padding and margin properties of the various navbar assets is failing to allow for the menu to resize properly on mobile.

JsFiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/phobrla/b9zpbejg/

[image: Screenshot]

---

```
<html>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">      

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">The Burkean<br/>Pentad</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Intro <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Act</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scene</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agency</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Purpose</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chande .navbar-inverse by .navbar-default

Regards!

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b9zpbejg/2/)

```
    .navbar-outer .navbar-default{
  background:red;
}

<div class="navbar-outer">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```